# Google Charts linechart formatted xcord,ycord,legendlabel

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm new to google charts and can't seem to figure out how i would do something of the following:

I want to make a data table that has my xcord,ycord,legendlabel. I'm trying the following:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);   

            data.addColumn("number","reps");
            data.addColumn("number","weight");
            data.addColumn("string","legendlabel")

            //data.addColumn("string","workoutname");

            data.addRows([[150, 10,"workoutA"],
                          [300, 2,"workoutB"],

                        ]);
```

However, it isn't working obviously because we have two different types, number and string.

Is there a way i can specify the xcord, ycord then have a label for this point, then if there are multiple labels that are the same it forms a line graph?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

I there some reason you're initializing the empty data variable and then adding to it?

Why not do this:

```js
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['legendlabel', 'Reps', 'Weight'],
  ['workoutA', 150, 10],
  ['workoutB', 300, 2]
]);
```

…which works in my test at the [Google Code Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart).

Though, it probably doesn't display what you want, since you're comparing two scalars values of different scales (one is 2-10, one is 150-300). What sort of graph are you hoping to see?

This question may help you with dual y-axes: [Can Google Charts support dual y-axis (v-axis)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256672/can-google-charts-support-dual-y-axis-v-axis)

Comment: Yes it doesn't really display what i want. What i really want to do is have a data datable something like [[xcord,ycord],legendlabel] is that possible any way

Comment: I'm hoping to see the weight value on the y axis, rep value on the x axis, then lines according to a legend label i.e. workoutA would connect all the dots with workoutA label, then another legendlabel called workoutB connecting all of those dots etc.