# Defining attributes for two y axes in google column charts

Tags: google-visualization

i'm searching for a way to define two different y axis in a google column chart. I already found some help here: [Can Google Charts support dual y-axis (v-axis)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256672/can-google-charts-support-dual-y-axis-v-axis) and in various other posts

I managed to get the two axis in my chart and i could allign the data correctly to the different axis.

My problem now is that i don't seem to be able to give the two y axis different attributes. Everything i write into the brakets just seems to be ignored be google charts. If i set attributes for both axis it works - but i want for example two different titles...

It seems like i'm missing something important in my code

Here is my code what i'm trying to do:

```
function drawChart002() {
// grab the CSV
   jQuery.get("csv/compare_time_percent.csv", function(csvString) {

      // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
      var arrayData = jQuery.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: jQuery.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

         for(var i=1; i< arrayData.length; i++){
        var row = arrayData[i];
        for(var j=0; j< row.length; j++){
            var el = row[j];
            if(j == 0){
                row[j] = new Date(el);
            }
        }
    }

      // this new DataTable object holds all the data
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

      // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data, true);
     // view.setColumns([0,1]);

     // set chart options
     var options = {
        title: "",

        series:{0: {targetAxisIndex:0},
                1: {targetAxisIndex:1},
                2: {targetAxisIndex:1}
        },

        hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0)},
        vAxis: {0: { title: 'Unterschied in Prozent'},
                1: { title: 'Temperatur in Celsius', viewWindow: {min: -20, max: 20}}
        },



        curveType: 'function',
        legend:  { position: 'bottom' },
     };

     // create the chart object and draw it
     var chart_div = document.getElementById('div_002');
     var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('div_002'));

     var chart_div_print = document.getElementById('div_002_link');
     var chart_print = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('div_002_link'));

     // wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() methode
     google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
     chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
     document.getElementById('div_002_link').outerHTML = '<a href="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">Printable version</a>';
     console.log(div_002);
     });

     chart.draw(view, options);
  });
}
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart002);
```

but instead of using the titles google charts dosen't print any title for both axis, and he ignores the viewWindow option too

i hope my problem is clear and you can help me to find my mistake and help me with my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `vAxis`, should be `vAxes`

```
vAxes: {0: { title: 'Unterschied in Prozent'},
            1: { title: 'Temperatur in Celsius', viewWindow: {min: -20, max: 20}}
    },
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew i missed something small :) it works now perfectly :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your proyect