# Adding a specific y-axis for the line graph

Tags: javascript

By digging about and my previous posts or post I've been able to figure out how the series property is adjusted when building a combochart i.e.

```
      series: {1: {type: "line"},
                2: {type: "line"}}
```

Please see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr5eaevq/6/)

The next step for me is creating and linking individual Y-axis with each line related series.

As seen below in a combochart I want to add need a specific y-axis for the line graph.

[image]

Any ideas??

Comment: Is there something you want to know beyond whats in your [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603390/creating-a-multiple-y-axis-combo-chart/29731162#29731162](other question)?

Comment: On a side note some of your questions can be a little confusing and I suspect that is why people are voting them down and they aren't getting more attention.  You might want to check out [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x20x6f2u/2/) with a second axis using the same technique as shown in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603390/creating-a-multiple-y-axis-combo-chart/29731162#29731162).

```
    series: {1: {type: "line", targetAxisIndex: 1},
             2: {type: "line"}},
    vAxes: {
            0: {
                title: 'axis1'
            },
            1: {
                title: 'axis2'
            }
        }
```

Comment: drs9222 ... I can't thank you enuf for your help .. i will give it a go this evening and let you know i got on ..

Comment: drs9222 ... thanks .. tried it and it sure draws the 2nd axis but upon adding dummy data for a 3rd line graph and adding 2: {
                title: 'axis3'
            } an additional Y axis wasn't drawn. I guess this isnt the way to add a 3rd axis .. I had a look at the API docs but cant seem to see how to add more than 2 y axis ..

Comment: @ANM - I've never tried more than two and when I did try to add a third to yours it failed.  The documentation does call this feature "Dual-Y" which implies that you can only do two,

Comment: @dr29222: thanks ... i also tried it and no success ... i'll see how to work round the issue .. workaround a - create separate plots for each line graph as shown in the image in my orgnl post ... then place each of the graphs in the same horizontal position as the div holding the combochart .. then change enable all the colors to be transparent with regards to everything on the plots but leave the y axis on each graph with its original colour .. it sounds crude but what do you think ..