# Adding line plot to combo chart

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add a line plot/graph to an existing combo chart - [see combo chart fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q46Xz/961/).. The data I want to use for the line plot ideally is something like this:

```
["Set 1", 900]
["Set 2", 700]
["Set 3", 500]
["Set 4", 300]
["Set 5", 100]
```

Now I've been through the [official line graph visualization tutorial](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) here and been through example post such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256672/can-google-charts-support-dual-y-axis-v-axis) which have been of great help in  working out how independent line graphs are generated.

But my objective is to plot several line graphs in the same plot as my working combo chart as seen in this [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2lBPXKQBuQHeF9PS0JpUHR0dXc&authuser=0).

Comment: I've done similar charts before and if I remember correctly the combo didn't combine well with the dual axis.  Also, your fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: I see .. Could you kindly suggest a way forward

Comment: Sorry for the delay on getting back to you.  I had to leave right after I commented yesterday and didn't get back to my home PC until now.  I've updated the "answer" I gave at work today to have a real solution for you.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to provide a real answer....

Your issue was the index on your series.  You have 2 series but the index was 0 base you were trying to turn the third into a line.

So this

```
series: {2: {type: "line"}}
```

needs to be this

```
series: {1: {type: "line"}}
```

Also, I believe the issue I mentioned in the comment was wrong.  I think you can do both a combo chart and a dual axis but you might run into issues with scale.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ueu9zva6/).

Comment: Really appreciate the help .. dunno how I would have figured out how to add independent line graphs into a combo chart .. I built on your fiddle here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/dr5eaevq/5/