# Understanding series property in Google Visualisation

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looking at grasping the meaning of Google Visualisations series property. So for example whats the meaning of the series statement below with regards to the dummy data I placed after the text.

```
    series: {2: {type: "line"}}
```

Using the data below does the above mean plot a line graph using data in the final column.

Dummy Datatable:

```
data.addRow(["Set 1", 900, 450, 50]);
data.addRow(["Set 2", 700, 550, 40]);
data.addRow(["Set 3", 500, 350, 30]);
data.addRow(["Set 4", 300, 100, 20]);
data.addRow(["Set 5", 150, 50, 10]);
```

OR

Using the above datatable does series: {1: {type: "line"}} mean plot a line graph using column two data?

Comment: The number in `series: {2: {type: "line"}}` and `series: {1: {type: "line"}}` is the zero based index of a column in the data that, in this case, will be graphed as a line in a combo chart.

Comment: I should also point out that the first value in the array for each row is the x-axis value.  So you have one x-axis value and 3 y-axis values indexed 0-2 as series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/wshxfkzf/).  This is the same as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676786/adding-line-plot-to-combo-chart/29706149#29706149) but using the data provided in this one.

In this case I used `series: {1: {type: "line"}}` so the first value of each row of data ('Set *') will be the x-axis.
The second value of each row of data (900,700,...) will be the series with index 0 and will be drawn as a bar.
The third value of each row of data (450,550,...) will be the series with index 1 and will be drawn as a line.
The forth value of each row of data (50,50,...) will be the series with index 2 and will be drawn as a bar.

[image: Output]

See the [official DataTable documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews) for more info.

Comment: Really appreciate the help .. dunno how I would have figured out how to add independent line graphs into a combo chart .. I built on your fiddle here it is: jsfiddle.net/dr5eaevq/5

Comment: The next step for me is creating and linking individual Y-axis with each line related series.